# Playing sound in multiple formats in real time

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

HTML5 presents the Audio tag for embedding sounds in web pages. However, support for different formats varies. IE, Chrome and Safari will accept MP3 files, while Opera and older versions of Firefox require WAV or OGG files. I do not have access to multiple formats for each of my sound files, and at this point I am tempted to try to run file conversions on each request requiring a different format. Is there a way of playing sounds irrespective of format, preferably without using Flash?

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that you support older browsers?  I just tested the latest version of Opera and it plays MP3s fine.  QuickTime can play MP3s as well, if they happen to have that installed.  You could use that as a fallback instead of Flash.  Other than that... there are apps out there to mass convert files from MP3s to other formats.

Comment: It is quite important that older browsers are supported, ideally at least 95% of the user base. Also, the idea is to integrate sounds directly into the site, without requiring a user to open a separate window with fancy controls just to hear a 'click' sound.

Comment: How old are we talking?  Because IE8 won't support the audio tag at all, no matter which audio format you use.

Comment: I was also considering fallbacks for that